# How to load data into Hive table

Tags: sql, hive

I'm using the hortonworks's Hue (more like a GUI interface that connects hdfs, hive, pig together)and I want to load the data within the hdfs into my current created table.
Suppose the table's name is "test", and the file which contains the data, the path is:
/user/hdfs/test/test.txt"

But I'm unable to load the data into the table, I tried:

```
load data local inpath '/user/hdfs/test/test.txt' into table test
```

But there's error said can't find the file, there's no matching path.

I'm still so confused.
Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said "**load the data within the hdfs into my current created table**".
But in you command you are using :

load data **local** inpath '/user/hdfs/test/test.txt' into table test

Using **local** keyword it looks for the file in your local filesystem. But you file is in **HDFS**.

I think you need to remove **local** keyword from you command.

Hope it helps...!!!

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using the hue and the output is showing not matching path. I think you have to give the complete path.
for example: 
load data local inpath '/home/cloudera/hive/Documents/info.csv' into table tablename; same as you can give the complete path where the hdfs in which the document resides.
You can use any other format file

Answer (score -2):

remove local keyword as ur referring to local file system